# docker-compose bitnami opentcart sendmail not found

Tags: opencart, bitnami

I am running locally the docker file from bitnami open cart, but every time an email is sent a message in the terminal is displayed

> opencart_1  | sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found

I am wondering if there is a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami does not ship "sendmail" binary in any of our containers, it is not a good practice for sending emails in a production environment, They recommend to use a SMTP from a thirdparty provider and configure the SMTP settings to send emails from the application.

You can check the configuration https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-opencart#smtp-configuration